# "neither ... nor " alternative

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis, neither-nor

Is it correct ? 
I don't currently have neither an irish residence nor an irish bank account yet

or I could say : I don't have an irish residence and  an irish bank account yet

Comment: Your first example contains a double negative (don't + neither) and is wrong in Standard English. Either delete the word "don't" or  write it as  _I don't currently have (either) an Irish residence or an Irish bank account_. Your second example is okay, but I'd replace "and" with "or". Btw, you should capitalise Irish.

Comment: Besides the problem of double negation, you may emphasize your saying this way: "*I don't yet have an Irish residence. Neither have I an Irish bank account*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't currently have neither an Irish residence nor an Irish bank
>   account yet.

...is *incorrect* English, 'don't ... neither' would be a double negative.  (Exception: if uttered in a rich Irish brogue, 'don't ... neither' becomes charmingly emphatic.)

> I don't have an Irish residence **and** an Irish bank account yet

...also *incorrect*.  It leaves the possibility that you might have *one*, but not the other.

Better:

> I don't have an Irish residence or an Irish bank account yet.

Or, (by rearrangement, remove 2nd redundant 'Irish'):

> I don't have an an Irish bank account or residence yet.

Or:

> I have neither an Irish residence, nor an Irish bank account, yet.

Answer (score 0):

Predominantly, when two negatives are used in a sentence, it usually just cancels each other out resulting in the sentence having a weak positive meaning (Except probably in cases where you're using double negatives to emphasize something). Since you've already mentioned 'You don't currently have' which indicates a negative there is no need to use 'neither... nor'.

You could re-write this sentence as 'I don't currently have an Irish residence or bank account' or 'I don't have an Irish residence or bank account yet'.

If you want to read more about double negatives, here are some links that might help,

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative#Two_negatives_resolving_to_a_positive
2. https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/sentences/negatives/2/double-negatives/

Hope this helps!